# Failed to save 'pubspec.yaml': The content of the file is newer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to ask if the error cannot save in pabspac.yaml and welcome.dart, yesterday I added a background image and I called the picture in pabspac.yaml when I saved, an error appeared. anyone help me. guide me to learn flutter.[this is the error statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mZmU.png)

```
name: wali_yudharta
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  lottie: ^0.4.0+1
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  rxdart: ^0.22.2

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - img/irvan.png
    - img/Splashscreen.png
    - img/soon.json
    - img/Login.png

  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I found an error when I entered - img / Login.png in assets. This png login is used at welcome.dart

Comment: hello, please show your whole pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: I have added the entire pubspec.yaml code or you can also see on my github [link](https://github.com/irvanthole/waliyudhartaapp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when you don't save the file in visual studio code and close it and then edit the file using another editor so visual studio have the files contents and it compare it to new contents of file and if it found new content then it will show this error you can override if you think that the contents is changed or you can compare to see changes or may be discard them.

Comment: how to restore everything that I changed. or do I have to make an adventurous project from scratch?

Comment: Override the changes