# When I try to save I get enospc Error VSCODE

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

when I try to save one of the file of my workspace it gave me this error:

"Failed to save 'style.css': The content of the file is newer. Please compare your version with the file contents or overwrite the content of the file with your changes."

I'm a WINDOWS 10 user, and a newbie so I don't really know what to do about it, of course I have a lot of free space on my pc

I tried to restart the software first and than the computer.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62908477/) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to save 'pubspec.yaml': The content of the file is newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62908477/failed-to-save-pubspec-yaml-the-content-of-the-file-is-newer)